# Can't login with a unique username into mysql

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am trying to connect a existing server files with my new machine. I need to be able to connect with a username "????", but for some reason mysql is not accepting that.

[Using root as username it prompts me into entering password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fUZP.png)

[As for using ???? as username it acts as if I asked to see help..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQhYH.png%27)

Can I make mysql accepting ???? as a username? If so - how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS?  Windows `cmd` needs `chcp 65001`.  Linux might need the terminal to be set to UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry for not including OS right away. I am using ubuntu 20.10. 
It seems that it is already en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 by default. This is not the issue..

Comment: What quoting do you use?  Are you coming from a shell script or from some app?

Comment: Do you have more than one file with a four-character name in your current directory? If so in a Unix shell (but not some other systems) `mysql -u ????` expands to something like `mysql -u bear fork hair nerd taxi tree` which is course not a valid set of arguments for `mysql` and thus produces the 'help' message.